# Format only 1 column in Excel to forced text and keeping all others as number while export to Excel from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel

I have to download an Excel file with 10 columns in that in one column I am getting 70696918000007 as '7.06969E+13' in the Excel everything is showing up properly when I add

```
sbResponseString.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"> <head><style> td {mso-number-format:"\@";} </style><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=windows-1252\"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>" + worksheet_name + "</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head> <body>");
```

but I don't want to convert all other columns as text as I have to find sum of the other columns. So how to format only 1 column of Excel to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple I just added one class to the column where I wanted to convert to string

```
 DataGrid dataExportExcel = new DataGrid();
 dataExportExcel.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 dataExportExcel.DataBind();
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
   {
   dataExportExcel.Items[i].Cells[5].Attributes.Add("class", "Invoice")
    }
```

Then changed the Code by

```
sbResponseString.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"> <head><style> .Invoice {mso-number-format:\'@'}</style><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=windows-1252\"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>" + worksheet_name + "</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head> <body>");
```

Simply added seperate style for Invoice Class